# Why do i get openssl error unknown option for -adext?

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate, csr, subject-alternative-names

I am attempting to generate CSR using openssl with subject alternative names however i get an error stating no options for adext. See command below.. I am using **OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips**

```
openssl req -new \
-newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout {domain-name}.key \
-out {domain-name}.csr \
-subj "/C=GB/ST=test/L=/O=test/OU=test/CN={domain-name}.com" \
-addext "subjectAltName = DNS:first.{domain-name}.com,DNS:second.{domain-name}.com,DNS:third.{domain-name}.com,DNS:www.{domain-name}.com.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

The error implies you have a typo and missed a `d` out of the command when you entered it the first time (`-adext` != `-addext`).

If you take exactly what you've shown in the question and just remove all the `{}` so it uses `domain-name.com` as the domain, it fails because `L=` needs a value, but if you add in a value it then works just fine:

```
$ openssl req -new \
> -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout domain-name.key \
> -out domain-name.csr \
> -subj "/C=GB/ST=test/L=foo/O=test/OU=test/CN=domain-name.com" \
> -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:first.domain-name.com,DNS:second.domain-name.com,DNS:third.domain-name.com,DNS:www.domain-name.com.com"
Generating a RSA private key
................+++++
...........................................+++++
writing new private key to 'domain-name.key'
-----
```

p.s. you also have an extra `.com` on the end

Comment: Thanks but i have just copied what you have there and it does not work... i did not miss out a "d", i actually have "addext" not "adext" in there. Also i think this is a version issue no ?

Comment: You've effectively answered your own question.  While version 1.1.1 has the `-addext` option, [version 1.0.2 doesn't](https://web.archive.org/web/20210103034813/https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-req.html).

Comment: Since the answer is not related to typo, but a version issue, the answer should be changed.